# Image background android

Tags: android, image

I have a linear layout with an image background. 
I read the article about [Supporting Multiple Screens](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html).
I know that android stretches the images in order to fit them to different screen
But my question is should I create the background image as 9-patch or create a different sizes of the image for the different screens?

Comment: you should need to follow the android basic structure of drawables and this is how the multiple screens are supported.

Comment: As I remember you can put multiple resources per screen size. So android will use the resource that fits the screen.

Comment: @Goot yes I know that, but is it necessary to create a different sizes of that image ? this image is used as the application background image